# Determine limit using DCT

Tags: integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

I want to determine the following limit (for $\alpha>0$)
$$
\lim_{\alpha \to +\infty} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^\alpha)}dx
$$
(call this integrand the fuction $f_\alpha$). Now, this can be done by using the dominated convergence theorem. In order to apply this theorem I should verify three conditions:

1. $\forall x \in (0,\infty): \lim_{\alpha\to\infty} f_\alpha < \infty$
2. For al $\alpha$>0 and all $x\in (0,\infty)$ there exists a function dominating $f_\alpha$
3. The dominating function is also integrable.

**Attempt**

I was already able to verify that this function $f_\alpha$ will only be integrable for $\alpha>1/2$. However, I'm not sure why condition (1) should hold if I take $x$ to be very small, then this limit won't be finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^{\alpha}=\exp(\alpha \log(x)).$ If $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$ and $x\in (0,1),$ then the exponent is negative, and so the whole thing tends to $0$. Then, $\sqrt{x}(1+x^{\alpha})$ tends to $\sqrt{x}$.

Conversely, if $x>1,$ then $x^{\alpha}$ tends to $\infty$ as $\alpha$ does, and so, the fraction tends to $0$.

For $x=1,$ the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$

Thus, our limit function is a.e. equal to $1_{(0,1)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Now, we'd like to find a dominating function for our family. Note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^{\alpha})}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}},$ no matter the value of $\alpha$. Unfortunately, this bound is not integrable over the entire line. Now, for $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon$ and $x\geq 1,$ we have  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^{\alpha})}\leq \frac{1}{x^{1+\varepsilon}}$, which is integrable on $[1,\infty)$. Thus, declaring our dominating function to be $f(x)=1_{(0,1)}(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+1_{[1,\infty)}\frac{1}{x^{1+\varepsilon}}$ works for $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon$ and allows you to apply DCT.

Comment: Thank you for the smooth answer! Ps. this holds for all $\epsilon>0$, thus in the last line we can abandon the epsilon and use $\alpha \ge 1/2$?

Comment: Never mind! I get it